# Let the user see if an entry is disabled in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way to visibly indicate that an Entry is disabled? The only thing that happens when you disable an entry is that you cannot click on it anymore, but its appearance doesn't change.

I tried to change the background to a darker one but it doesn't change if the entry is disabled.

```
def blockentry(evento):
    if self.addVotoFrameEntry2["state"] == NORMAL:
        self.addVotoFrameEntry2["state"] = DISABLED
    elif self.addVotoFrameEntry2["state"] == DISABLED:
        self.addVotoFrameEntry2["state"] = NORMAL
self.addVotoFrameCheck = Checkbutton(self.addVotoFrame, text="Oggi", font=("Helvetica 11"), variable=var)
self.addVotoFrameCheck.pack(anchor=SW)
self.addVotoFrameCheck.bind("<Button-1>", blockentry)
self.addVotoFrameEntry2 = Entry(self.addVotoFrame, width=10)
self.addVotoFrameEntry2.pack(pady=(0, 10))
```

Comment: Can you include your code please?

Comment: Do you use the tkinter Entry or the ttk Entry?

Comment: tkinter one, however, i've just added the code

Comment: did you use `background=` or `disabledbackground=` - [Entry](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm)

Comment: @furas I didin't know the _disabledbackground_ option. Now it works, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Entry` has not only `background` but also `disabledbackground`, `insertbackground`, `readonlybackground`, `selectbackground` - so you have to use correct variable :)

See more on [Entry](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm)

BTW: text color is `foreground`, `disabledforeground`, etc.

Comment: Does exist a similar way to set the text of a disabled entry? I tried disabledtext, but it doesn't worked.

Comment: text color is `foreground`, `disabledforeground`, etc.